# Problem with sorting of umlaute in a glossary (pkg glossaries)

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, sorting

I'm currently facing a problem concerning sorting of glossaries.
I'm writing my thesis in german, so I also have some umlaute like "ä","ö" and "ü" in my acronyms. For example there is an acronym "ÖGD".
Now the problem is that the sorting of acronyms doesn't work as expected. The acronyms with the umlaute are at the top of the list. Normally the "Ö" for example should be after the "O".
The following MWE illustrates the problem.

I know that there is a parameter -g or -s when using `makeindex`. The problem is that the glossaries package comes with a `makeglossaries`-perl script. I don't want to touch the perl-script. So, is there another possibility to get my glossary and acronyms-list sorted right?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,ngerman]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bibgerm}
\usepackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}

\usepackage[style=longheader,toc,acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries         

\begin{document}    

 \newacronym{B2B}{B2B}{Business to Business}
 \newacronym{oegd}{\"OGD}{\"offentlicher Gesundheitsdienst}
 \newacronym{HL7}{HL7}{Health Level Seven}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Currently the acronyms-list is sorted like this:

- ÖGD
- B2B
- HL7

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the sort key to change the sort order. Also you should better put groups around the accents (see the paragraph before section 4.1. in the docu):

```
\newacronym[sort=OEFFE]{oegd}{{\"O}GD}{{\"o}ffentlicher Gesundheitsdienst}
```

You can also try to use `xindy` instead of `makeindex`.

Answer (score 9):

Quoting `glossaries`' manual from section 2.4 (Sorting options):

> **sort** This is a `key = value` option where the option can only have one
>   of the following values:
>
> - *standard*: entries are sorted according to the value of the `sort` key
>     used in `\newglossaryentry`? (if present) or
>     the `name` key (if `sort` key is missing);
> - *def*: entries are sorted in the order in which they were defined (the 
>     `sort` key in `\newglossaryentry` is ignored);
> - *use*: entries are sorted according to the order in which they are used
>     in the document (the `sort` key in `\newglossaryentry` is ignored).
>
> The default is `sort=standard`.

This explains the sorting you're getting: the `name` is used since you didn't specify the `sort` key and it's *not* the label you're using but what gets displayed: `\"OGD`, `B2B` and `HL7`. `\"O` is probably treated as a symbol and thus listed first.

You have at least two options now: specify the `sort` key as Ulrike proposed, or define them in the order you want and add the `sort=def` to `glossaries`' options.

(You might also use `\newacronym{OEGD}{ÖGD}{öffentlicher Gesundheitsdienst}` since you're allowing `utf8` input, anyway, …)