# Accented words sorted incorrectly in glossary

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package to create an Irish-English dictionary, but the accented letters are being treated as coming after all not-accented letters. I've noticed many questions in which the problem was having accented **labels**, but that is not my case, here labels are just integer numbers with no meaning, and the document compiles perfectly fine.

Here is a MWE showing the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[irish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{1}{name={trá},description={Beach}}
\newglossaryentry{2}{name={buail},description={Hit}}
\newglossaryentry{3}{name={toradh},description={Fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{4}{name={bád},description={Boat}}
\newglossaryentry{5}{name={turtar},description={Turtle}}
\newglossaryentry{6}{name={traicé},description={Trachea}}
\newglossaryentry{7}{name={éadach},description={Cloth}}
\newglossaryentry{8}{name={tae},description={Tea}}
\newglossaryentry{9}{name={ith},description={Eat}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[title={Irish-English Glossary},nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

[image]

After running pdflatex-makeglossaries-pdflatex, the PDF output has the words sorted incorrectly when it comes to accented letters:

1) If the first letter is accented, it goes all the way down, after all other letters (in my example, *éadach*).

2) If the second letter is accented, it shows at the end of the corresponding letter (*bád* after *buail* when it should precede it).

3) If the third letter is accented, its two first letters are sorted correctly, but the accented one is treated as coming at the end (*trá* after *toradh* and before *turtar*, but after *traicé* too, when it should be between *toradh* and *traicé*).

And the problem shows with other positions of accented letters in words, but these are the most frequent.

I wonder how can I get the words sorted in correct order (that is, a letter is in the same position of the alphabet no matter if it's accented or not).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using the sort key? You could try sort={tra} and so on in the main argument.

Comment: it's `b\'ad` instead of  `bád` ;)

Comment: @Echo I didn't know that option, it's pretty tedious to do in all words but it works, thank you. ((Edited after seeing Alessandro Cuttin's answer))

Comment: related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69300/177

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though using UTF8 is correct, you can (almost) obtain the right sorting by using the [accents defined by LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8859/177) or by [better grouping the accented letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69300/177). I had to somewhat cheat with the `sort` key only for *éadach*.

Looking at the `glossaries` manual, section *1.4 Multi-Lingual Support*

> Note that although a non-Latin character, such as é, looks like a
>   plain character in your `.tex` file, with standard LaTeX it’s actually
>   a macro and can therefore cause expansion problems. You may need to
>   switch off the field expansions with `\glsnoexpandfields`. This issue
>   doesn’t occur with XELaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
>
> With `inputenc`, if you use a non-Latin character (or other expandable) character at the start of an entry name, you must place it in a group, or it will cause a problem for commands that convert the first letter to upper case

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[irish, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{1}{name={tr\'a},description={Beach}}
\newglossaryentry{2}{name={buail},description={Hit}}
\newglossaryentry{3}{name={toradh},description={Fruit}}
\newglossaryentry{4}{name={b\'ad},description={Boat}}
\newglossaryentry{5}{name={turtar},description={Turtle}}
\newglossaryentry{6}{name={traicé},description={Trachea}}
\newglossaryentry{7}{name={\'eadach},description={Cloth},sort={eadach}}
\newglossaryentry{8}{name={tae},description={Tea}}
\newglossaryentry{9}{name={ith},description={Eat}}

\begin{document}

\glsaddall

\printglossary[title={Irish-English Glossary},nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Alessandro, this solves the issue altough I am curious: is `babel` and/or `inputenc` not "interacting" correctly with `glossaries`? I wrote a lot of Spanish in LaTeX just using UTF-8 and `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` never having to write an accent like `\'a`.

Comment: I've updated the answer in that sense